# Python theano: how does the R-operation work?

Tags: python, theano

I am executing the following on theano:

```
>>> import theano
>>> import theano.tensor as T
>>> x = T.dvector('x')
>>> y = T.dvector('y')
>>> f = T.dot(x,y)
>>> Jy= T.Rop(f,x,y)
>>> fun = theano.function([x,y],Jy)
>>> fun([1000,2000,3000],[2,4,8])
array(84.0)
```

However, if I calculate a simple example by hand I have:

```
x = [x1,x2,x3]
y = [y1,y2,y3]
f = [x1y1,x2y2,x3y3]
df/dx = |y1, 0, 0|
        |0, y2, 0|
        |0,  0,y3|
(df/dx)*y = [y1^2, y2^2, y3^2]
```

Thus I would expect a result of `[4, 16, 64]`, but instead I get the sum of these. What is the `Rop` calculating differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is caused by a misunderstanding of what `theano.dot` is doing in your sample code.

`theano.dot(x, y)` is equal to the scalar `34000` given your example inputs because it is computing the vector inner product not the element-wise product, as your hand example suggests you expect.

One can get the result you expect by changing

```
f = T.dot(x,y)
```

to

```
f = x * y
```